# Magento v1.8 Customer Login, Add to Cart, Checkout Not Working on multi-websites system

Tags: php, magento

Magento main website china2you.co.uk is working fine but not the sub-site. We have configured 2nd website on subdomain cpost.china2you.co.uk which is malfunctioning after a lot of design changes.Its main functions: Add to cart not working, login not working, register does register new customer (can be seen from admin) but visitor cannot login after that. When visitor add items into cart it shows Cart is Empty.

We have setup the cookie life time to 86,400, disabled & flushed cache and applied form_key as well, None of the solutions worked which are available online.

We have shifted the sites to new server and all was working on new server 2 weeks ago. After design changes on cpost.china2you.co.uk something wrong has happened. There are 70K+ products in the system.

Any help in this regard would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Reason seems to dictate that one of the "lot of design changes" broke it. Since we don't know what those changes are we can't easily diagnose this problem. Do you have any place you can narrow it down? Can you check whether the website actually queries the database when a visitor attempts to login? etc. etc.

Comment: We have logged the sql queries and found following:   Query SELECT `c2ycustomer_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `c2ycustomer_entity` WHERE (email = 'support@eglobalsolution.com')
     86 Query SELECT `c2ycustomer_entity`.* FROM `c2ycustomer_entity` WHERE (entity_id ='6')
     86 Query SELECT `c2ycustomer_entity_varchar`.* FROM `c2ycustomer_entity_varchar` WHERE (entity_id ='6') UNION ALL SELECT `c2ycustomer_entity_int`.* FROM `c2ycustomer_entity_int` WHERE (entity_id ='6') UNION ALL SELECT `c2ycustomer_entity_datetime`.* FROM `c2ycustomer_entity_datetime` WHERE (entity_id ='6')

Comment: 86 Query DELETE FROM `c2ycaptcha_log` WHERE (type = 2) AND (value = 'support@eglobalsolution.com')
     86 Query DELETE FROM `c2ycaptcha_log` WHERE (type = 1) AND (value = '39.34.142.46')

Comment: 86 Query SELECT `c2yindex_process`.* FROM `c2yindex_process` WHERE (`c2yindex_process`.`indexer_code`='catalog_product_flat')

Comment: Can you put the query as an edit in the question? Have you confirmed that the user that is selected exists? (I guess it does since the next query uses `id='6'`.) What are the next steps used by the login process? Password checking perhaps? Or setting a cookie/session response?

Comment: [SOLVED] after debugging all the login procedure i found out that session is not working at all, then i figured out that in index file $_SESSION was used before Mage::run which stopped normal session handling mechanism by Magento. Thanks EWit for your time to help us!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] after debugging all the login procedure i found out that session is not working at all, then i figured out that in index file $_SESSION was used before Mage::run which stopped normal session handling mechanism by Magento, I updated the session handling code to make everything working again!

Comment: This question was a bit unconventional for Stackoverflow since it's no direct Q&A. But glad to have been of service.